# Showing $\sin^{12}\theta+3\sin^{10}\theta+3\sin^8\theta+\sin^6\theta+2\sin^4\theta+2\sin^2\theta-2=1$, given $\cos\theta=\sin^2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\theta \in \mathbb R$ such that $\cos\theta=\sin^2\theta$. Then$$\cos{\theta} + \cos^{2}{\theta} = 1 \tag a$$We need to prove that:

$$\sin^{12}{\theta} + 3\sin^{10}{\theta} + 3\sin^{8}{\theta}+\sin^{6}{\theta}+2\sin^{4}{\theta}+2\sin^{2}{\theta}-2=1 \tag b$$

I can't even start to solve, wolfram alpha, and gpt does brute force, but I feel there is *elegant* way (it is class 10 problem, tho hots one), tried to rise $(a)$ to power $6$ and derive $(b)$ but no success.

Comment: reduce higher power of $sin\theta$ using $cos\theta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you'll find this elegant: Notice that the right hand side of (b) factors nicely as
\begin{equation}
(\sin^4\theta + \sin^2 \theta)^3 + 2(\sin^4\theta + \sin^2 \theta) - 2
\end{equation}
Furthermore, using (a), we have the two identities
\begin{align*}
\sin^2 \theta  &= 1 - \cos^2 \theta = \cos \theta, \\
\implies \sin^4 \theta &= \cos^2\theta
\end{align*}
and so
$$
\sin^4\theta + \sin^2 \theta = \cos^2 \theta + \cos \theta = 1.
$$
Plugging this in the above factorization verifies (b).

Answer (score 1):

As given that $$ cos \theta + cos^2 \theta = 1, $$ from this we get  $ cos \theta = sin^2 \theta$. 
Now, $$ sin^{12}\theta+3sin^{10}\theta+3sin^8\theta+sin^6\theta=(sin^4\theta)^3+3.(sin^4\theta)^2.sin^2\theta+3.sin^4\theta.(sin^2\theta)^2+(sin^2\theta)^2=(sin^4\theta+sin^2\theta)^3=\{(sin^2\theta)^2+sin^2\theta\}^3=(cos^2\theta+sin^2\theta)^3=1^3=1 \ (as, \ cos\theta=sin^2\theta).$$ 
So we get $$\sin^{12}{\theta} + 3\sin^{10}{\theta} + 3\sin^{8}{\theta}+\sin^{6}{\theta}+2\sin^{4}{\theta}+2\sin^{2}{\theta}-2=1+2sin^4\theta+2sin^2\theta-2=1+2cos^2\theta+2sin^2\theta-2=1+2-2=1. \ (as, cos\theta=sin^2\theta).$$ 
Hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$, hence $\cos \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta = \sin^2 \theta$, that's a good start.

Then you have: $\sin^{12} \theta + 3 \sin^{10} \theta + 3 \sin^8 \theta + \sin^6 \theta = \sin^6 \theta \cdot (\sin^2 \theta +1)^3 = \cos^3 \theta \cdot (\cos \theta + 1)^3$

From here on, it's always further, simplying $\sin^2$ to $\cos$ until you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the polynomial:
$$
f(s) = s^{12} + 3 \, s^{10} + 3 \, s^{8} + s^{6} + 2 \, s^{4} + 2 \, s^{2} - 3\ .
$$
It factors as:
$$
f(s) = \left(s^{8} + 2 \, s^{6} + 2 \, s^{4} + s^{2} + 3\right)\left(s^{4} + s^{2} - 1\right)\ .
$$
Now observe that from the given relation $\sin^2\theta=\cos \theta$ we get $\sin^4\theta=\cos^2 \theta=1-\sin^2\theta$, so $\sin\theta$ is a root of $s^4+s^2-1$, thus also of $f(s)$.